# Importing test library to Robot Framework for user defined methods

Tags: python, robotframework

I created Testclass.py as below:

```
class Testclass(object):
    def testmethod(self):
        print "Hi"
```

And I accessed it from my `login.robot` file as

```
Library   Testclass
```

and I called method `testmethod` from my Robot Framework suite file.

But when I run through command line `pybot login.robot` I get import error:

`Error in file 'login.robot': Importing test library 'Testclass' failed: ImportError: No module named Testclass`

If I don't define class and only define method it works.

Comment: when you run the test, is your working directory the same folder as Testclass.py?

Comment: Yes all the files are in same folder. I found the work around, I copied Testclass.py to PYTHONPATH /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/.

Comment: I am sure there is easier way rather than copying libraries to pythonpath manually

Comment: If all your libraries are in a single folder, you can simply modify your PYTHONPATH, you don't have to physically move the files to some other folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is simply that robot cannot find your library. It only looks in places in your PYTHONPATH. So, one solution is to add the path to your library to your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

You can also use the --pythonpath option to pybot if you don't want to alter your PYTHONPATH.

For example, assuming your file `Testclass.py` is in the folder `./robot/libraries`, you can run your tests like this:

```
pybot --pythonpath ./robot/libraries my_test_case.robot
```

For more information about this option, see the section [Configuring where to search libraries and other extensions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#configuring-where-to-search-libraries-and-other-extensions) in the robot framework user guide.

You can also specify the file by path, if you want to hard-code the path of the file into your test case. If you do this, the class name inside the file must match the filename (eg: `class Testclass` in `Testclass.py`).

For example:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | robot/libraries/Testclass.py
```

This is covered in the robot framework user guide, in the section [Specifying library to import](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#specifying-library-to-import).

Answer (score 0):

If your Testclass.py Library and .robot file are in the same folder use following:

```
Library  Testclass.py
```

> Make sure that class and python file Name are the same.