# Selenium2library import for keyword access in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

please note that attempt is to write python script and not in robot files

I have two files

---

### api.py

```
import requests
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from robot.api import logger
from robot.running.model import Keyword

bi = BuiltIn()

class APIRequests:
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST CASE'
    def something():
      return "some string/value"
```

In the same folder, i have another file which I script robot file

### login.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library         BuiltIn
Library         api.py
*** Test Cases ***
Valid Weathercheck:
    ${abc} = something 
    Log to console ${abc}
```

When I execute from the command console 
    robot login.robot
I get an error message saying the 'No keyword with name 'something' found.'

Query2

When we want to use some existing web driver modules which are existing in python , i am unable to find the needed documentation around it on how I can link/import them as ready keywords

Comment: Is this for a script to be run standalone, or are you writing a keyword library?

Comment: Does this answer give you what you need to know? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23704655/7432

Comment: Thanks a Lot Bryan, I have been going through your responses across the tag in the mean while. Let me take a moment to thank you for the great community support provided.

Comment: Let me rephrase the queries

Comment: I hope the queries are now clear, please advise your suggestions so that i can move forward

Comment: Please limit your question to a single subject. For `Query2`, see if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23704655/7432

Comment: Thanks a lot!! - Query 2 is certainly answered, I will try it out -

Answer (score 1):

Robot won't automatically create an instance of your class, unless the class name is the same name as the filename. In your case you have a file named `api.py` but a class name of `APIRequests`. You either need to change the name of the file to `APIRequests.py`, change the class name to `api`, or import the keywords as `api.APIRequests`.

From the [robot framework user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-names):

> Python classes are always inside a module. If the name of a class implementing a library is the same as the name of the module, Robot Framework allows dropping the class name when importing the library. For example, class MyLib in MyLib.py file can be used as a library with just name MyLib.

Comment: It is actually a typo , apologies for that - apirequests is the name of class . I found that there is a different error in the log which i have overlooked  , the file apirequest with the class name also as apirequests is available in the same folder/directory but I do see an error like "Importing test library 'apirequests' failed: ImportError: No module named apirequests"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832629/importing-test-library-error-for-user-defined-methods - thanks, got the answer and response for both the queries